# Java String.split pass in precompiled regex for performance reasons

Tags: java, regex, performance

As the question states given the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
         String test = "Cats go meow";  
         String[] tokens = test.split(" ");
   }
}
```

is it possible to precompile that regex in the split function along the lines of this:

```
public class Foo
{  
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
         String test = "Cats go meow";  
         String[] tokens = test.split(pattern);
   }
}
```

Comment: split(" ") is faster (see comment below)

Comment: @michael_s I added a comment, please counter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Also, make `pattern` static so the static method `main` can access it.

```
public class Foo
{  
   private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
         String test = "Cats go meow";  
         String[] tokens = pattern.split(test);
   }
}
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the `split` method in String, you can use String's `split` or Pattern's `split`, but String's `split` compiles a `Pattern` and calls its `split` method, so use `Pattern` to precompile a regex.

Comment: Yes `Pattern#split(string)` is roughly 25% faster. See perf benchmark by Oracle (slide 72)  https://shipilev.net/talks/joker-Oct2014-string-catechism.pdf

Comment: thanks man.  I got this in sonarcube scan and didn't understand their solution, yours is easy :)

Answer (score 7):

```
public class Foo
{  
   private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
         String test = "Cats go meow";  
         String[] tokens = pattern.split(test);
   }
}
```

Comment: Also consider making the pattern static and final.It would save compilation overhead for every instance

Answer (score 7):

No - I think that would be a bad idea!

Looking closely at the source code of the split-method - there is a shortcut implemented in case the string is only of one character (and does not contain a regex-special character)

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    /* fastpath if the regex is a
     (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
        RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
     (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
        the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
     */
    char ch = 0;
    if (((regex.value.length == 1 &&
         ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
```

so - split(" ") should be a lot faster.

On the other hand when using regexes it is always a good idea to make them static final members.

edit:

The source code JDK1.7 and OpenJDK 7 seems to be identical for String.split - have a look yourselves:
[Lines 2312ff.](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)

So - for more complicated patterns (1 or more spaces for instance):

```
   static final Pattern pSpaces = Pattern.compile("[ ]+");
```

Comment: hmm I would contest that a String.split inside a while loop would invalidate this claim.  Care to counter?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - what while loop?

Comment: just because my program doesn't illustrate a `while` loop does not mean that other programs don't have them.  If I wrote a parser that had to tokenize a series of lines, there would be a `while` loop

Comment: so what - the answer was specific for split(" ") which is significantly faster than using split(pattern), where pattern is Pattern.compile(" "). It doesn't matter if it's in a loop. No need for downvoting... honestly

Comment: Actually there is a reason for the downvote, the information you provided is flawed.  As an aside you cannot rely on the source code of a library to always be the same.

Comment: Yes - if you're using some fancy Open-JDK maybe - I just looked at the source code of the Oracle-JDK (formerly Sun) which hasn't changed since Version 1.4 - Alright - nevermind - we're talking of the implementation of class `String` btw

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Pattern.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead:

```
String[] tokens = pattern.split(test);
```

Comment: hmm actually, this doesn't address the pre-compiling of the pattern as it is the compile step that takes the "most" amount of time

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I don't understand your last remark. Once you have an instance of `Pattern`, the regex has been compiled, and `pattern.split()` requires no further compilation.

Comment: My mistake I thought there was a way to instantiate Pattern by itself.